# AIAA Journals: Double-spaced or not? Single-column or not?

Tags: templates, aiaa

I have started writing a publication for an AIAA journal. Now, the journal website leads me to [Journal Author](https://www.aiaa.org/publications/journals/Journal-Author?_ga=2.29404415.1941017229.1624098498-1804670978.1619778342) which gives the [link to the Overleaf template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/latex-template-for-the-preparation-of-papers-for-aiaa-technical-journals/mqqbqqvyhtwm#.WbKsbsiGNPY). This template is double-spaced and single-column. However, articles from the [current issue](https://arc.aiaa.org/toc/jsr/current) are single-spaced and double-column. Should I follow the former or the latter?

EDIT: The issue with following the journal's instructions is that they also require a page limit whereas previous papers that are single-spaced and double-column go up to twice this limit. In that case, if I follow the journal's instructions, I end up reproducing just a quarter of the information in comparison to other papers that the journal has published in the current issue.

Comment: do whatever the journal says for _submission_ they probably reset the final publication version in any case. (Some journals don't use tex at all for publication even if they accept author submissions in TeX, some use TeX but with proprietary fonts, and some just print what the author supplied)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle makes a lot of sense! Thanks!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle unfortunately, I just realized that there's more to the story. I've modified the question.

Comment: the same answer. You are submitting to a journal, you need to follow their rules otherwise  most likely they just reject the submission. If you think their rules are misleading or wrong write to the journal and ask but no third party help site like this is going to tell anyone to ignore a journal's own submission guidelines.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks!